# How to take access to internal storage in android 11?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, file, file-management

I want to access `full access of internal storage` but I have tried so many things didn't able to access in android 11. then I used solid explorer also available in the play store which is giving full access to internal storage. can someone tell me how to achieve this in android 11.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have two options, either acquire `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` which needs some approval from google play AFAIK!
Or set the targetSdk to 29 and use requestLegacyExternalStorage

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage

> Apps that run on Android 11 but target Android 10 (API level 29) can
> still request the requestLegacyExternalStorage attribute. This flag
> allows apps to temporarily opt out of the changes associated with
> scoped storage, such as granting access to different directories and
> different types of media files. After you update your app to target
> Android 11, the system ignores the requestLegacyExternalStorage flag.

But remember, you can use targetSdk 29 until August 2021 (November if it's an update) and after that you have to targetSdk 30
https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/target-sdk

In other words, Google is trying to prevent apps from accessing external storage for privacy concerns. I guess we should follow Google's guidelines (forget about the user's files)